# Which channel coding technique is suitable for wireless SPIHT compressed image: Reed-Solomon or convolutional code?

Tags: image-processing, compression, channelcoding, image-compression, fading-channel

I want to transmit a SPIHT-based (Set Partitioning In Hierarchical Trees) image compressed image over a wireless fading channel, which will be suitable as channel coding technique: [Reed-Solomon](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~guyb/realworld/reedsolomon/reed_solomon_codes.html) or [convolutional code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolutional_code)?

Answer (score 1):

The channel coding used has little to do with your source coding. So, this depends on how you model your channel (and noise, and interferers), and what kind of errors you're willing to tolerate. Saying "SPIHT-compressed image" answers neither!

Answer (score 1):

If you have the opportunity to use the SPIHT structure, you can look for **error-resilient** extensions:

- [Error Resilient Compression and Transmission of Scalable Video](http://www.cipr.rpi.edu/people/faculty/pearlman.html/papers/spie00_cp.pdf), Sungdae Cho  and William A. Pearlman
- [Error-Resilient and Error Concealment 3-D SPIHT](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-13681-8_41), Jie Zhu, R. M. Dansereau, Aysegul Cuhadar
- [Error-resilient video coding with improved 3D SPIHT and error concealment](https://doi.org/10.1117/12.476433), Sungdae Cho  and William A. Pearlman

The following sources use Reed-Salomon:

- [A GPU-Accelerated Wavelet Decompression System With SPIHT and Reed-Solomon Decoding for Satellite Images](https://doi.org/10.1109/JSTARS.2011.2159962), Changhe Song,  Yunsong Li,  Bormin Huang
- A[n Efficient Source–Channel Coding for Wireless Image Transmission Over Underwater Acoustic Channel](https://doi.org/10.1007/s11277-017-4167-6), Hanaa S. Ali, Asmaa M. Atallah, M. I. Abdalla

Comment: Oh, Nice! That's actually pretty clever :)